# All my Kentico live sites 404 and the previews do as well

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, kentico

I created a site in Kentico 12 and using the live viewer was working fine.  Now its started 404ing every time I try to go to the site either by the URL: localhost:8080/Kentico12_[sitename] or by viewing the site through the live site feature.  I a new site and it does the same thing.  Additionally, page preview 404s as well.  I have tried changing domain alias' and URL patterns but it doesn't seem to work.  If anyone has a solution or some useful documentation to point mee toward that would be appreciated.
I can get into the back end of the site no problem by going to http:localhost8080:/Kentico12_Admin
I can reinstall Kentico 12 if needed but would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling is not the answer.  Make sure you have the site properly setup in IIS first.  A simple setup is to set the root of the site in IIS to the root of your MVC site.  Then under that main site, create a virtual application and set that to the root of the `CMS` directory and call that virtual application "cms".

Then navigate to localhost/cms and you should be directed to the Kentico login page.  Once you've logged into the Admin interface, update your site's domains.  The `Site domain name` should be `localhost/cms`.  The `Presentation URL` should be `http://localhost`.

If after you've made those changes and you're still getting 404's we'll have to look into other possible issues maybe in your web.config.

Comment: I can get into the back end of the site no problem by going to http:localhost8080:/Kentico12_Admin

Comment: Then do you have a license key for localhost:8080?  Or is there a specific need to add the port number after the domain?  Kentico sees a domain with a port as a separate license key. Lastly, have you double-checked the site domain fields aI mentioned?